Update key of entry in react-native-async-storage
Wondering if there is a way to update the key of an entry when using the react native package react-native-async-storage. I could not find anything in their docs.
If not creating an identical new entry with the new key and deleting the old one could be a solution.

First of all, I did not understand your question completely, I am answering you according to what I have understood.
You can do like this for update the key.
useEffect(() => {
  checkEntryKey();
}, []);

const checkEntryKey = async () => {
  try {
    const latestKey = "newKey"; // your latest entry key
    const storedKey = await AsyncStorage.getItem("entryKey");

    if (storedKey !== null && storedKey === latestKey) {
      // If key already exists, do not change it
      console.log("already exists -", storedKey);
    } else {
      // If the stored key is different or doesn't exist, update it
      if (storedKey !== null) {
        // If key doesn't exist, delete it
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("entryKey");
        console.log("Old key deleted :", storedKey);
      }
      // Update it
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("entryKey", latestKey);
      console.log("New key Inserted:", latestKey);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error -", error);
  }
};

